# What is the name of this fundamental math theory?

Tags: logic, philosophy

I remember reading a while back on Wikipedia about a theory that says all of Mathematics can be reduced to a set of string manipulation rules and don't need to have any actual meaning. So e.g. if 2+2=4 then wherever we see 2+2 we replace it with 4 and so solve bigger equations.

I thought it was called String Manipulation theory, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

(It's not limited to calculus, but I couldn't find any other appropriate tag).

Comment: Maybe not a theorem, but rather a philosophy of mathematics called formalism?

Comment: If that is true I am going to my university to demand my money back for my studies...!

Comment: You may enjoy reading [Gödel, Escher, Bach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theory that you described, "all of mathematics can be reduced to a set of string manipulation rules and do[es]n't need to have any actual meaning," doesn't seem to be a math theory (as in your title) at all but rather a philosophical theory about the nature of mathematics.  Specifically, it seems to be a (rather extreme) version of formalism.  By googling "formalism", you should be able to find more than you ever wanted to know about this topic.

Comment: Is this something like the  _"theory of everything"_  in physics, but in mathematics, i.e. some form of highest abstraction that includes _"everything"_ within it?

Comment: @Ziezi As far as I know, the hoped-for "theory of everything" in physics is supposed to be physics, not philosophy about the nature of physics.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was just trying to make an analogy, so the question is purely philosophical and there is no such practical theory, right?

Comment: yes. Thank you. This is the wiki link:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)

Answer (score 2):

You are presumably referring to **syntax** — the part of **formal logic** that deals with the study of (formal) mathematical statements and deductive proofs.

A related notion is that of **string rewriting**, which also has uses outside of formal logic.